# python: Function pointer breaks polymorphism

Tags: python, polymorphism, function-pointers

I would like to store a dict of function signatures in a base class and have child classes override some of these function signatures. However, it seems like my implementation breaks polymorphism. I want some suggestions on an elegant alternative. Thanks!

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.FXN[key](self)

    def f(self):
        pass

    def g(self):
        pass

    a = 1
    FXN = {
        1 : f,
        2 : g
    }

class Child1(Base):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.FXN[key](self)

    def f(self):
        print 'hi'

class Child2(Base):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.FXN[key](self)

    def f(self):
        print 'hey'

    def g(self):
        print 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Child1(1) # Nothing happens
    Child2(1) # Nothing happens
    Child2(2) # Nothing happens
```

Edit: Clarified problem

Edit 2: Clarified problem again

Comment: In a more complicated case, each of the constructors can take in an object of some type. The key is an enum that identifies the object type and dictate what path of instance initiation to take.

Solution from Bruno: Mister Bruno below gave me a relatively elegant solution.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.FXN[key](self)

    def f(self):
        pass

    def g(self):
        pass

    FXN = {
        1 : lambda self: self.f(),
        2 : lambda self: self.g()
    }

class Child1(Base):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.FXN[key](self)

    def f(self):
        print 'hi'

class Child2(Base):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.FXN[key](self)

    def f(self):
        print 'hey'

    def g(self):
        print 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Child1(1) # hi
    Child2(1) # hey
    Child2(2) # hello
```

Comment: Honesty, Why would you ever want to do that instead of using standard language notation? Is your problem an  [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: My actual problem is to get an elegant way to do single-parameter constructor overloading. I am not a fan of big blocks of if-elif-else

Comment: And why do you think Python's (and that of most other OOPL) original method is not elegant?

Comment: Define 'original method'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not "function pointers", just "functions" - Python's functions are first class objects. And it indeed won't work as you expect, since what you store in `Base.FXN` are the local (to the class statement) functions `f` and `g`.

There are a few possible solutions, depending on your *real* use case (which you don't say anything about, and I suspect a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)), one of the simplest being defining these functions as simple wrappers and delegating the implementation to another function (which you then override as needed in child classes), ie:

```
class Base(object):
    def f(self):
        return self._f()

    def _f(self):
        pass

    def g(self):
        return self._g()

    def _g(self):
        pass

    FXN = {
        1 : f,
        2 : g
    }


class Child1(Base):
    def _f(self):
        print 'hi'

class Child2(Base):
    def _g(self):
        print 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = Child1()
    c2 = Child2()
    c1 = Child1.FXN[1](c1) 
    c2 = Child1.FXN[2](c2)
```

A more involved (but possibly more efficient, once again depending on the *real* problem you're trying to solve) solution could be based on decorators (class decorators or function decorators), custom descriptors or (and/or...) a custom metaclass.

EDIT : given the edited example, two simple solutions:

use lambdas:

```
 class Base(object):
     def f(self):
         pass

     def g(self):
         pass

     FXN = {
         1 : lambda self: self.f(),
         2 : lambda self: self.g()
     }

 for base in receive_some_bases():
     base.FXN[1](base) 
     base.FXN[2](base)
```

use `getattr()`:

```
class Base(object):
    def f(self):
        pass

    def g(self):
        pass

    FXN = {
        1 : "f",
        2 : "g",
    }

for base in receive_some_bases():
    getattr(base, base.FXN[1])() 
    getattr(base, base.FXN[2])()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have updated my example to reflect my problem

Comment: I like your lambda approach. I tried it out. It seems like you need an extra () in the end for the function to invoke. It looks a little bit ugly with all these parenthesis but it is likely the best answer I will get by far.

Comment: The getattr() approach is not favoured because there is no direct link between the string and the method. Suppose one renames the method in Eclipse, the change will not be auto-detected

Comment: "It seems like you need an extra () in the end for the function to invoke" => No, it's just you that forgot the parens in the lambda, should be `lambda self: self.f()`

Answer (score 1):

FXN is a class variable and not bound to the child classes. It also references the original f, g function objects in the dict, not the names defined in the child classes. How should it, as they not even exist when the bas class' body is executed?

Why not use normal methods? Those would be bound to each class. As an alternative, you could bind the functions to each instance using `types.MethodType` in `__init__()`.

And, remember: all attributes of an instance/class are already stored in a dict of the object (`__dict__`), so there is actually no need to create your own.

Comment: It's true that __dict__ has the method pointers but I'd like the methods to be mapped to certain keys of my choice. Let me re-define my scenario a bit

Comment: @user1836155: That dict is just a dict. You forget that Python has dynamic typing, different than Java, C++, etc. You can basically add an attribute to any object. And in Python is **everything** an object. So you can just bind any function to an instance using `type.MethodType` (I corrected my Answer in this aspect; no idea why I wrote ClassMethod).

Answer (score 1):

This will make your example do what you seem to want:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FXN = {
            1 : self.f,
            2 : self.g
        }
    def f(self):
        pass

    def g(self):
        pass


def receive_some_bases():
    return [Child1(), Child2(), Child1(), Child2(), Child1()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for base in receive_some_bases():
        base.FXN[1]()
        base.FXN[2]()
```

Update:
Based on more recent updates to your question it sounds like you want a factory of some sort. A dictionary to classes might fit the bill:

```
FXN={
    1: Child1,
    2: Child2
}
def receive_some_integers():
    return [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for value in receive_some_integers():
        c = FXN[value]()  # instantiate Childx
        c.f()             # call a method on instance
```

Comment: I've considered that, but then I'd be having this object per instance instead of per class. It works but I want to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

`FXN` is irrelevant if you have the object instance

**Try this:**

```
class Base:
    def f(self):
        pass

    def g(self):
        pass

class Child1(Base):
    def f(self):
        print 'hi'

class Child2(Base):
    def g(self):
        print 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = Child1()
    c2 = Child2()

    c1.f() 
    c2.g()
```

Comment: You'll get an error with `c1 = Child1.f()` as you're calling the unbound method `f` on the class and not the instance.  Use `c1.f()` or `Child1.f(c1)`.